# Stripe returning token but can access it

Tags: node.js, token, stripe-payments

I am getting a stripe token back from my `stripe.tokens.create` now I can assign it to a variable inside it but I need to call that variable outside the callback. I was thinking global variable but then thought it might not work. I know the code examples I have found use `req.body.stripeToken` but my `req.body` comes back with a blank object `{}`. I can not find any guides on this for Node.js only stuff like Ruby and PHP.

Comment: I can copy and paste the token after `console.log` then assign it to the variable I need and it all works but soon as I try and do it dynamically it fails.

Comment: You should take the token obtained via your Stripe.js / Checkout integration and then pass it off to your backend charge processing route, either by submitting the form or an AJAX request. There's a super minimal Express / node example here, you can see how i use bodyParser to parse the url encoded body, and pull out the token id, https://stackoverflow.com/a/46636212/5108826

Comment: I am using a stripe middleware called `stripe-webhook-middleware` it came as part of my boilerplate I downloaded and am trying to fix. The code for the route is found here under the postBilling section

https://github.com/joshk132/asset-management/blob/master/server/controllers/users-controller.js

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve