# Req.body not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, request, stripe-payments

I am using a form to submit to stripe using POST and the route of `/user/billing`, well I need to access the stripe token coming back which I asked about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46669259/stripe-returning-token-but-can-access-it) but since `req.body` is blank I also can't get the card data from the form to submit to stripe. Should my `stripe.tokens.create` be somewhere other than my route?

Comment: What code do you want? The whole project can be found at https://github.com/joshk132/asset-management I can only include so much here so look there to see it all.

Comment: Welcome to SO. We can help you with your code, if you manage to get a minimal, complete and verifiable example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Not sure you need code to answer where the stripe tokens create should be. What good would code do? Genuine question.